# how to include cout in c++ programs?

Tags: c++

I'm I using terminal in ubuntu. I've installed g++ package for compiling c++ programs. But if I try to compile a program, it is giving an error that 'cout is not declared in this scope', even though I've included iostream header file.
What should I do??

Comment: Post a small example of what you are doing.

Comment: How is iostream included?  Is it with the `<>` symbols?

Comment: Did you do `#include <iostream>`?

Comment: Thank you a lot... it's working by putting std::cout instead of just cout...

Comment: You forgot to read your C++ book.

Answer (score 3):

Try using `std::cout`, instead of just cout.

Answer (score 2):

Read in more detail about [namespaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namespace) in c++. cout happens to be in the namespace called std.

After declaring your headers you can do `using namespace std;` and you don't have to use `std::cout` every time and use only cout, but that isn't [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?rq=1). instead you could declare only what you need.

ex: `using std::cout;`  `using std::cin;`  `using std::string;` that way you don't have to use `std::cout` everywhere in your code and use only cout or cin

Comment: Thanks. This was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you don't have build-essential ? It's mandatory in order to compile correctly on ubuntu.

Comment: @Ulamspi: If he has installed the `g++` package, then he has `libstdc++` already, as it is a dependency of `g++`; `build-essentials` isn't an additional requirement (although `build-essentials` is nice as it includes other useful tools). It is also not mandatory to have `build-essentials` to compile software with gcc.